# How can I get output of df -Th to echo particular column value in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have got the output of `df -Th` into a test.dat file. Is there a way we could get the particular value from `df -Th` in specific word such as
`/dev/xvda is mounted on /dev and has file system type tmpfs`

I have tried the following but could not figure out completely.

```
#!/bin/bash
df -Th
df -Th > test.dat
filename="test.dat"
sed 1d $filename | while IFS=, read -r filesystem Type mountedOn
do
echo "$filesystem is mounted on $mountedOn and file system type is $Type\n"
done < $filename
```

The output of `df -Th`:

```
Filesystem     Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev           devtmpfs  7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs     1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p2 ext4      916G   81G  789G  10% /
tmpfs          tmpfs     7.7G  441M  7.3G   6% /dev/shm
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Concerning your question, `/dev/xvda` is not mounted at all, according to your output. How would you like this case to be handled?

Answer (score 0):

You have more than three fields, so you need to supply more field names to `read`; and the fields are not comma-separated, so `IFS=,` is definitely wrong here. Also, you should generally avoid temporary files; and if they cannot be avoided, you mustn't use a static file name (because then you can't run two instances of your script in parallel, and, more seriously, predictable file names open up possibilities for symlink attacks).

However, this is a lot more natural with Awk.

```
df -Th |
awk 'NR>1 { print $1, "mounted on", $NF, "type", $2 }'
```

Comment: `NF>1` is not skipping the first line. Update it to `NR>1`

Answer (score 0):

At least one of the strings you are trying to extract may contain blank characters—it is likely uncommon, but nothing prevents a mount point from having white spaces in its path. Hence, parsing `df`'s output may not work as expected.

Given that [you are on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59703134/1), chances are that you have `df` from [Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/). It should provide a handy `--output` option, which lets you specify a list of fields to print.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for dev in /dev/sd*; do
    printf '%s '  "$dev is mounted on"
    printf '%s '  "$(df --output=target "$dev" | tail -n +2)"
    printf '%s '  "and file system type is"
    printf '%s\n' "$(df --output=fstype "$dev" | tail -n +2)"
done
```

Of course, this only works correctly under the assumption that mount points and file system types may not have trailing newline characters (which would be removed by command substitution; this can be [worked around](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/383217/315749), though).
Also, the output will include unwanted items unless you make sure that all the device paths `/dev/sd*` expands to are actually mounted. You may do this, for instance, by adding `findmnt --source "$dev" 1>/dev/null || continue` as the first command inside the loop. `findmnt` is provided by [util-linux](https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux).

Alternatively, assuming you have `findmnt`, its `-r` option (raw output format, all potentially unsafe characters are hex-escaped) may be used to make its output reliably parsable:

```sh
findmnt -n -D -r -o source,target,fstype |
  awk '{ print $1,"is mounted on",$2,"and file system type is",$3 }'
```

With the added benefits, compared to my previous suggestion, of efficiency (only two calls to external tools) and protection against changes to mount points that may happen between consecutive `df` calls.
The other used options are meant to remove the headings (`-n`), mimic `df` output, needed to exclude pseudo file systems (`-D`), and select/order the fields to print (`-o`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is how will i do it.

```
while read -ra line; do
  [[ ${line[0]} == Filesystem ]] && continue
  printf '%-15s is mounted on:  %-15s and file system type is:  %s\n' "${line[0]}" ${line[-1]}" "${line[1]}"
done < <(df -T)
```

Obviously he spacing is not robust enough but hey! :-)

In bash the built in read has an -a option and what it does is save the output of lines in an array. so **"${line[0]}"** is the first field/column in this case (and so on). We test if the first field is Filesystem and if it is we skip that line using the builtin **continue** then process the rest of the remaining lines. Lastly printf has some formatting capability so we use it.
the **<()** is called process substitution and in order to read from it we use the **<** redirection sign. see man bash

```
PAGER='less +/^[[:space:]]*process\ substitution' man bash
```

for some info about ProcSub.